# Scala cannot infer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, type-inference

I have a very simple snipper of Spark code which was working on Scala 2.11 and stop compiling after 2.12.

```
import spark.implicits._
val ds = Seq("val").toDF("col1")

ds.foreachPartition(part => {
  part.foreach(println)
})
```

It fails with the error:

```
Error:(22, 12) value foreach is not a member of Object
  part.foreach(println)
```

The workaround is to help the compiler with such code:

```
import spark.implicits._
val ds = Seq("val").toDF("col1")
println(ds.getClass)

ds.foreachPartition((part: Iterator[Row]) => {
  part.foreach(println)
})
```

Does anyone have a good explanation on why the compiler cannot infer `part` as an `Iterator[Row]`.

`ds` is a DataFrame which is defined as `type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]`.

`foreachPartition` has two signtures:

- `def foreachPartition(f: Iterator[T] => Unit): Unit`
- `def foreachPartition(func: ForeachPartitionFunction[T]): Unit`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is because since `2.12` **Scala** provides SAM support and the **Spark** API was not designed for that, as such the method overload produces an ambiguity. And since **Spark** no longer caress about **Scala** users but **Java** and **Python** ones, this probably will never be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is to help someone facing the issue and workaround of what can be done to get around this issue.

You can convert Dataframe to rdd and then use foreachpartition and you will be able to compile and build your code.

```
ds.rdd.foreachPartition(part => {
  part.foreach(println)
})
```