# Spark 3.0 DataFrame foreachPartition method does not work

Tags: apache-spark

The following code

```
val df = List(1,2,3,4,5).toDF()
df.foreachPartition(p => p.foreach(println(_)))
```

Works well in spark 2.4 with scala 2.11, but with Spark 3.0 with scala 2.12, it failed with this error:

```
error: value foreach is not a member of Object
df.foreachPartition(p => p.foreach(println(_)))
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066034/scala-cannot-infer

Comment: you can use df.rdd.foreachpartition to get around with this error.